# is growl_notify only for macs? Is there a Window's Alternative

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, growlnotify

here is the gem:
https://github.com/visionmedia/growl

How can i tell if this a Mac only app?

Comment: Is this not related to software tools commonly used? why did you close this???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I currently use [Growl for Windows](http://www.growlforwindows.com/gfw/default.aspx) as Joe said.

In my Gemfile:

```
group :test do
  gem "ZenTest", "~> 4.6.2"
  gem "autotest-growl", "~> 0.2.16"
  gem "autotest-rails-pure", "~> 4.1.2"
end
```

Create a file named `.autotest` in your home directory, probably `C:\Users\username\` and put `require 'autotest/growl'` at the top.

Ensure Growl is running and when you run `bundle exec autotest` the tests will output notifcations through growl.

nb. double-check gem version numbers, it took me a little while to find the right combination of versions to work together and it may have changed since.

Avoid the 'fsevent' gem, as it's mac-specific.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I haven't implemented just yet. I'll try it tonight when I get home.  Just to clarify, do I need all three of the gems you listed to make growl work, or just "autotest-grow"?

Comment: `ZenTest` is the gem which includes the `autotest` program, `autotest-growl` is then the connector between `autotest` and `growl`. `autotest-rails-pure` is a plugin for autotest with rails and seems to help autotest locate tests and other things, it's not well documented. The `-pure` part is important, it's a dependency-free version so it won't hold you back from updating ZenTest where appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Growl is a Mac app. To make similar thing in Windows, use [Notification and Notification Area API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee330740%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the info.  What inform's you that this app is for Macs only. (for future reference)

Comment: Oh, I see. Growl is a stand alone app.  Are there any gems that work with the Notification and Notificaion Area API?

Answer (score 0):

The original Growl is Mac-only, but someone else came out with a [Growl for Windows](http://www.growlforwindows.com/gfw/default.aspx).

Comment: cool. so, I should be able to run that ^ gem with Growl for Windows, or does it need special configuration?

Comment: Growl for Windows claims to be compatible with Growl, so I would expect that it should just work.